# Make it do that a label shows the opposite length of a text box?

Tags: vb.net

In Visual Basic I made it do that a label shows the length of a textbox, now how do I make it so that it shows how many characters you have left to type in the textbox? What I mean is like on Twitter how you have a limit to so many characters. I want it also so that when it gets to ten or lower the label turns red, and then above 10 the label turns black. Forgive me if the question shouldn't be in this forum, I just can't find out how to do this.

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense.  You can type a lot of iiiii's in a text box, few wwwww's.  It automatically scrolls when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Forms you could write

```
 label1.Text = (textBox1.MaxLength - textBox1.Text.Length).ToString();
```

Comment: Better `TextLength`, not `Text.Length`.

Comment: Now how could I make it do that when the textboxs length gets to 10 or under it turns red, but when it gets ten or higher it turns back to black?

Comment: @Evy0311, really you should post another question. Don't worry there are thousands of people ready to help.

Comment: Ok. I posted another question but on the programmers forum. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @GSerg, could you explain? I have always used the Text.Length (more out of habit than reasoning. Why is better?

Comment: @Steve `Text.Length` is all we had in VB6, so no problems with using that there. For winforms however `TextLength` is better, because it queries the textbox directly for the length of the buffer, whereas `Text.Length` copies all the contents into a string and counts it.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer has an error because it is trying to convert a decimal to a string, so you need to wrap that in brackets and call .ToString() as for your colours idea I used percentages. If you have used more than 50% and less than 75% of your character allowance, then make the text orange. If you have used more than 75% then make it red.

```
  lblRemaining.Text = string.Format("{0} characters remaining", (textBox1.MaxLength - textBox1.TextLength).ToString());
  decimal percentageUsed = ((decimal)textBox1.Text.Length / (decimal)textBox1.MaxLength) * 100;
  if (percentageUsed >= 50 && percentageUsed < 75)
    lblRemaining.ForeColor = Color.Orange;
  else if (percentageUsed >= 75)
    lblRemaining.ForeColor = Color.Red;
  else
    lblRemaining.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```